# How to get the value of an id from the url-jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

url: `testPage?id=67346756384/indexList`

how to get the location of the id from the above url? I tried this:

```
getIdLocation = $(location).attr("href");
id = getIdLocation.substring(getIdLocation.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);
```

but that gets me "indexList". I need the id.Any ideas??
Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I get query string values in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values-in-javascript)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get the value from the URL parameter?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/979975/how-to-get-the-value-from-the-url-parameter)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [first and second parameters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substr) of `substr` to designate the start and length of the string to be extracted:

```
var id = str.substring(str.lastIndexOf("=")+1,str.lastIndexOf("/"));
```

Answer (score 2):

I have used [this](http://www.jquerybyexample.net/2012/06/get-url-parameters-using-jquery.html) function, it works great.

It will be something like this for your case, pretty simple:

```
var id = GetURLParameter('id');
```

Full code from the link:

```
function GetURLParameter(sParam){
    var sPageURL = window.location.search.substring(1);
    var sURLVariables = sPageURL.split('&');
    for (var i = 0; i < sURLVariables.length; i++)
    {
        var sParameterName = sURLVariables[i].split('=');
        if (sParameterName[0] == sParam)
        {
            return sParameterName[1];
        }
    }
}​
```

Although, I prefer to pass the url as a parameter. It will be easier to write unit tests for that.